# How to make different font sizes on graphs with specific point sizes

Tags: r, plot, fonts, font-size

I'm trying to get specific font sizes for scatterplots based of Nature guidelines. I'm told to keep all my point sizes for text at 7 so I've used `par(ps = 7)`. However, I need a different font size for the main title. I need 8 point font size. I understand I can use `cex.main` but I'm so confused about the ratios to get that exact point size. Can someone tell me how to get exactly 8 point font size for the title.

Here is my code for one of the graphs:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), ps = 7)

par(mar=c(6,4,1,0))

#Plot for Confirmed Tick Data
plot(tick1_data$Year, tick1_data$average_cases,
     main = "a",
     cex.main = 1/1.14, ## I'm not sure this is giving me 8 point font size ##
     type = "p",
     pch = 19,
     cex = 2,
     col = '#BF0436',
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "Average Confirmed Cases",
     ylim = c(0,308),
     bty = "n",
     xaxt = "n")
mtext(side = 1, text = "Year", line = 5)
par(bty = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = seq(2006, 2017, by = 1), las = 2)
rect(2004, -10, 2100, 50, border = NA, col = "#d3d3d365")

lines(spline(2005:2017, tick1_data$average_cases, n = 100), col= "#BF0436", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: Use a simple plot to experiment. For example: `par(ps=7); plot(1:10, 1:10, main="Title", cex.main=8/7)` should be about right. It's hard to tell since the difference between a point size of 7 and 8 is pretty small. But this is a plot on the default device. For publication you want to plot directly to a graphics device, e.g. postscript or tiff depending on what the journal specifies. Capturing the plot on the screen and saving it can easily lead to changes in the font size.